# The function "is_expr_granted" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to install the new Admingenerator Bundle (symfony2admingenerator/generator-bundle). Some of the generated templates (like *List/results.html.twig) requires the Twig function "is_expr_granted" which should be in the jms/security-extra-bundle .. The issue is that the Twig extension (Twig/SecurityExtension) doesn't seem to be loaded. Has anyone experienced this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable `expressions` in the jms/security-extra-bundle. Add the following/edit your `config.yml`/`security.yml` to hold the following:

```
jms_security_extra:
  expressions: true
```

With expressions enabled, the twig extension and thus the `is_expr_granted` will be loaded.